# React Slideshow problems

Tags: reactjs

I'm new here jaja, and also new in react, i did a beginner course in youtube i highly recommend, it's a 5 hours course x.x, i learn somethings there and one of the codes from the examples i tried to re-used for building my own slide show component. I want some some advises and also to now if my code is in a good path.

I want to display a text for each image but i still don't know how, i also have a js file that have a const with states to save an id url or a label for the image but don't know how to use it x.x.

//principal js Code

```
class SlideShow extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            currentImg: ImgList, 
            url: "1.jpg"
        }
        this.handleNextImg = this.handleNextImg.bind(this)
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        console.log("Click!!!", this.state.currentImg.length)
    }
    handleNextImg(id){
        console.log("Click!!!", id)
        this.setState(prevState => {            
            const updateImg = prevState.currentImg.map(image => {
                if(image.id === id){
                    if (image.id === this.state.currentImg.length){
                        image.id = 1
                    }else{
                        image.id = image.id + 1     
                    }                           
                }
                return image
            })
            const imgName = id + ".jpg" 
            return {
                currentImg: updateImg,
                url: imgName
            }
        })    
    }
    render(){
        const imgUrl = this.state.currentImg.map(items => <SlideBt key={items.id} items = {items} 
            handleNextImg={this.handleNextImg}/>) 

        return(
            <div>    
                <img src={this.state.url}  alt="Error img"/> 

                {imgUrl}

            </div>   
        )
    }

}
```

//this is the button code

```
function Button (props){
    const cStyle = {
        backgroundColor: "#000",
        width: "50px",
        height:"50px"       
    }
    return(
        <div 
            style={cStyle} 
            onClick={()=> props.handleNextImg(props.items.id)}
        />


    )
}
```

The images display correctly and when i click the button the img tag update correctly with the next image but, this button multiply it self when click it, at first i used just 1 picture, then when i added the second there where two buttons, and every time i click the button that multiply it self to 3, 4, 5, and so on every time i click it.

Comment: Please upload your code to https://codesandbox.io/. So I can find the problem

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/github/1eyasu/suitcase/tree/master/

Comment: If  click the squares in the button of the image it multiply, actually they should be a square but there is a rectangle because there is two squares x.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you render `SlideButton` with your image list. So if you have multiple images in you will render multiple buttons. You only need to render one button.

```
<SlideBt handleNextImg={this.handleNextImg} />
```

Another problem is that you have stored image list in `currentImg`. It is confused. This should only store one image not image list.

You also mutate image's id in image list. This is not a good idea. Your solution only works if your image name and id is number. If they are string, your app will not work. So I change `currentImg` to `currentImgIndex`. Below is full code

SlideShow.js

```
import React from 'react'
import './SlideS.css'
import ImgList from './ImgList'
import SlideBt from './SlideBt'

class SlideShow extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      imgList: ImgList,
      currentImgIndex: 0,
      url: "1.jpg",
    }
    this.handleNextImg = this.handleNextImg.bind(this)
  }

  handleNextImg() {
    console.log("Click!!!", this.state.currentImgIndex);
    let nextImgIndex = this.state.currentImgIndex + 1;
    if (nextImgIndex === this.state.imgList.length) {
      nextImgIndex = 0;
    }
    const nextImg = this.state.imgList[nextImgIndex];
    const nextImgName = `${nextImg.id}.jpg`
    this.setState({
      currentImgIndex: nextImgIndex,
      url: nextImgName,
    });

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <img src={this.state.url} alt="Error img" />
        <SlideBt handleNextImg={this.handleNextImg} />
      </div>
    )
  }

}


export default SlideShow;
```

SlideBt.js

```
import React from 'react'

function Button (props){
    const cStyle = {
        backgroundColor: "#000",
        width: "50px",
        height:"50px"       
    }
    return(
        <div 
            style={cStyle} 
            onClick={props.handleNextImg}
        />


    )
}

export default Button;
```